# purpose of MOSFET terminal designation

Tags: mosfet

I have seen that in discrete MOSFET, it is actually symmetrical, then what is the purpose of designating source and drain? if they can be interchanged. Is the designation is for just to indicate the direction of the body diode?

Comment: Have a look here:https://www.quora.com/Can-the-drain-and-source-of-a-MOSFET-be-interchangable

Answer (score 3):

In principle yes, they are *somewhat* symmetrical. In fact the original JFETs *were* symmetrical. Some JFET still has some symmetric behaviour, but I wouldn't bet on it unless it's clearly stated on the datasheet. In fact there is a different symbol for symmetrical JFET (the gate is on the center of the channel) while a common JFET has the gate arrow on the source.

However, no, you can't flip over a MOSFET and hope it will work correctly. It's actually a fabrication issue. If you look at the wikipedia drawing

[image: Wikipedia MOSFET]

it seems symmetrical. But if you look at how it's actually built (also from wiki)

[image: DMOS]

(that is a DMOS, by the way, there are three or four other major ways to build them) you'll see that it is actually *not* so symmetrical (and that without looking into the dopant ratio of the various zones).

It also shows why the drain is *always* the heat sinked terminal, it's simply the biggest one and the nearest to the package.

Comment: Adding to the asymmetry: commonly the source and body are connected together in the first image, creating the body diode and why Vgs is what controls channel formation.

Comment: I just want to add that this question and answer apply only to **discrete** MOSFETs, such as those used in power applications. In its purest form a MOSFET is symmetrical 4-terminal device, and the source and drain can alternate depending on their relative voltages.

Comment: Even discretes are often arrays of thousands of MOSFET (IIRC the first were the hexfets). Even trench are not symmetrical since the gate is almost buried in the source. In principle yes, they are symmetric like the old JFETs but now they are technologically refined to have distinct source and drain identities. Of course if you are drawing directly on silicon almost anything goes